# Sql Management Status Bar fields

Tags: ssms

I am in Microsoft SQL server Management Studio and I see at the bottom there is a status bar with Ln(line) Col(column?) and Ch(character?)

I have noticed that Col and Ch are always the same.  What are these 2 fields supposed to be and does one give me any additional information?

Answer (score 1):

Col is Column and Ch is Character.
Put some tab characters into the line and you will notice them differ. Column will grow faster.